# Why does json pointer use tilde as the escape character?

Tags: jsonpointer

The JSONPointer notation ([rfc6901](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901)) allows you to denote a location in a JSON document as a string.

I was surprised to see that the specification uses a tilde '~' as the escape character?
Why was this chosen rather than something more conventioal like a backslash ''?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason backslash cannot be used is that backslash already has a meaning in JSON and it is desirable to be able to include a JSONPointer in a JSON document without having to double escape it.

If you read the specification carefully you will note:

> 5. JSON String Representation
>
>    A JSON Pointer can be represented in a JSON string value.  Per
>      [RFC4627], Section 2.5, all instances of quotation mark '"' (%x22),
>      reverse solidus '\' (%x5C), and control (%x00-1F) characters MUST be
>      escaped.
>
>    Note that before processing a JSON string as a JSON Pointer,
>      backslash escape sequences must be unescaped.

Another reason is to allow for URI encoding.

According to [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/json-schema/iXHVCJk_zfQ) it was almost caret '^' instead.
Note also that tilde '~' is allowed in URLs whereas caret '^' is not. 
Though see http://jkorpela.fi/tilde.html for a counterpoint to tildes in URLs.